# Skip standard fields in GraphQL query results without strongly-typed items

Tags: graphql, layout-service

Is there an easy way to return all fields, while skipping standard Sitecore fields in GraphQL query results without strongly-typed items?
I know that I can use `fields(ownFields:true)`, but it will remove inherited fields from all templates, but I want to skip only standard ones with `__` prefix.

I have exclusions of standard field in my configuration, but this removes standard fields only from the  schema, but not from query results:

```
<fieldFilter type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.Filters.StandardFieldFilter, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
      <exclusions hint="raw:AddFilter">
           <exclude name="__*" />
      </exclusions>
</fieldFilter>
```

Comment: It might help if you can also share your sample GraphQL query to add more context and help with potential answers to your question.

Comment: I don't have specific query, I'm looking for generic approach to solve this issue, without the need of listing every field in my query via strongly-typed fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample query reference to tailor my answer, I think what you could leverage here are `query fragments` to help with multiple templates.

For example:

```
fragment itemDetails on Item {
  id
  name
  children{
    children(includeTemplateIDs:"{GUID}"{
      id
      name
      someotherfield
    }
  }
}
```

You can then leverage the fragment on your query

```
query GetPageContent($datasource: String!, $contextItem: String!) {
  datasource(value: $datasource) {
    ...itemDetails
 }
 contextItem(value: $contextItem) {
    ...itemDetails
 }
```

Ps: Please validate this syntax, just guiding on the approach here

Comment: what is "someotherfield" in your sample? As mentioned in my question I don't want to list all the fields in my query. I want the query to return all fields from item's template and all inherited templates except standard fields with __ prefix.