# Get all content items with presentation from GraphQL Content Search API

Tags: jss, graphql

Is there a way to get all content items with configured layout using GraphQL Content Search API?

I noticed, type children(requirePresentation: true) consists of an argument for requirePresentation to filter only items with presentation.

Can I extend GraphQL Content Search API and include this in the search schema?

Comment: Have you tried using fragments? Please have a look at this post: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28173/skip-standard-fields-in-graphql-query-results-without-strongly-typed-items/28184#comment41346_28184

Comment: Hi @JuliusA, yes I have tried fragments although when using fragments I have to explicitly drill down to all the children of children. In JSS 16+ they have already provided a hasLayout field which you can use to query field in search api. search(fieldsEqual: [{name: "hasLayout", value: "True"}])

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed in JSS 16+ where **hasLayout** computed field has been added to query content items with layout. You can use this query below to get this result.

```
{
  search(fieldsEqual: [{name: "hasLayout", value: "True"}]) {
    results {
      items {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're in JSS 15 below you need to add a computed field that checks if Layout exists and add it to your config.

```
public class HasLayout : IComputedIndexField
{
      public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
      {
          Item item = (indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem);
          return item.Visualization != null && item.Visualization.Layout != null;
      }
    
      public string FieldName { get; set; }
    
      public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```